Polars compute variance row-wise
I've the following dataframe
 df = pl.DataFrame({
     "col1": [1, 2, 3],
     "col2": [4, 5, 6],
     "col3": [7, 8, 9],
     "col4": ["a", "v", "b"], })

I'd like to add a column containing the variance for all columns except col4.
So far I've found this that could be a workaround the lack of horizontal computations in polars.
df = (
    (_df := df.with_row_index('i'))
    .join(
        _df.melt('i').group_by('i').agg(pl.col('value').var()), 
        on='i'
    )
    .sort('i')
    .drop('i')
)

However this only found when all columns are numerical. Is there a way to exclude col4 but to have it in the final dataframe?


selectors to filter out non-numeric columns.
concat_list() to get chosen columns into list.
list.var() to calculate variance.

import polars.selectors as cs

df.with_columns(var = pl.concat_list(cs.numeric()).list.var())

┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬─────┐
│ col1 ┆ col2 ┆ col3 ┆ col4 ┆ var │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ --- │
│ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ str  ┆ f64 │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪═════╡
│ 1    ┆ 4    ┆ 7    ┆ a    ┆ 9.0 │
│ 2    ┆ 5    ┆ 8    ┆ v    ┆ 9.0 │
│ 3    ┆ 6    ┆ 9    ┆ b    ┆ 9.0 │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴─────┘


very elegant! thank you!
